# I want to format my hard drive and install Lubuntu from DVD- Where do I start?

Tags: installation, lubuntu, format

I have 256 MG ram.  I don't really need XP.  I ran Lubuntu with live CD but could not install it with XP (which I don't really need).

My computer is for back up only.  I need something to access the internet quickly months down the road with out updating the OS and Virus program.

I need step by step directions or to be pointed to a web site with those directions.

Comment: Visit [this site](http://lubuntu.net/) for instructions

Answer (score 1):

That machine should run Lubuntu alright.  You might want to get the alternate installer which is text based however if you've already run "Try Lubuntu" then it should be fine, if a little slow.  You can just select Install from the first menu, or there should be a selection for it after you boot to the desktop.

You've already done the hardest part (getting the machine to boot the LiveCD/USB) and now all you need to do is install.  The defaults will most likely work fine if you are formating the entire drive for use with Lubuntu.  There are some step-by-step instructions [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/InstallingLubuntu).

Comment: I was unsuccessful installing from live CD.  I tried using Google but was informed that I did not have enough memory or another process was blocking it.

Comment: I used WUBI and during that process I was told I needed 256 MB of ram and I only had 255 MB.  I tried it anyway.  I am looking for a "low resource" installer.  I read that installation can be a resource hog, but Lubuntu is not.

Comment: If you download the alternate installer it won't need so much memory to install.  An alternative I found was to set up the partitions first from "try Ubuntu" or another linux utility boot disk and make the partitions including the swap partition first.  The installer will then run OK as It will find and use the swap partition.  It will run slowly, but it will at least be able to work reasonably well.